# clearTimeout not working in nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested, settimeout

I think it's got something to do with the nested functions, but they need to be this way. Why isn't it working? Am I doing something stupid? This is an isolated example and I must be using `$(this)`, so it seems I have to nest the functions?

*HTML:*

```
<div class="box"></div>
<ul>
<li>Hover box, it turns blue. Leave box, it turns red after 2 secs.</li>
    <li>If you hover back onto box before 2 secs is up, it's supposed to clear timer and keep box blue.</li>
    <li>It doesn't clear timer and after 2 secs the box still turns red. Why?</li>
</ul>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var t;

$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {

    $thisBox = $(this);

    clearTimeout(t);

    $thisBox.addClass('blue');

    $thisBox.on('mouseleave', function() {

        t = setTimeout(function() { $thisBox.removeClass('blue'); }, 2000);

     })

});
```

*​JSFiddle:* http://jsfiddle.net/ddbtZ/7/

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ddbtZ/3/

Your `.on()` shouldn't be nested. Effectively, that's attaching a new handler for every time you hover over the element.

EDIT: As per question clarification.

Use `.one()` instead of `.on()`

http://jsfiddle.net/ddbtZ/8/

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I need to be using ``$(this)``. Apologies for the bad explanation!

Comment: @AlexKempton - in the `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` event handlers context, both `this` instances are referring to the same owner. that's why it works.

Comment: @AlexKempton - Updated above.

Comment: This certainly answers the question here, doesn't actually fix my problem though, my isolation wasn't accurate enough. Will I get in trouble for accepting this and posting again (more detail, slightly different question) ?

Comment: Probably.
Just edit your above post and we'll keep refining further.

Comment: Sorted it! The event timer was firing lots because as you said, it's attaching a new handler every time and messing about with the wider scheme of things in my actual example. Used ``.off()`` to sort it. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Move your `mouseleave` from `mouseenter` event and it will work.

```
var t;

$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    $('.box').addClass('blue');
});

$('.box').on('mouseleave', function() {
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.box').removeClass('blue');
    }, 2000);
})​;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ddbtZ/4/

Comment: id add `if(t){clearTimeout(t);}` and `if(!t){setTimeout(function()....` just to ensure there no possibility of bubbling in the timer resulting in it running multiple times. Or trying to clear something thats not set but thats just me

Comment: note my bad timing, I'm not the down voter.. just putting it out there

Comment: Oops! My example was bad, I have to be using ``$(this)``.

Comment: @gdoron I'm sure it's time to add the *DV with comment only* feature. Otherwise, DV as a function doesn't make any sense :/